# How to go about designing a logo?

Tags: logo, branding, design-process

So this is a little more of a thought-process question. I am trying to design a logo for my personal passion project. But I have hit a creative wall, when it comes to designing the logo.

So of course there are things to consider when designing a logo, like

1. What should the logo represent (produkt)
2. What signal does the logo want to send (subtle or not subtle)

etc.

- I have a very clear idea about this, but I just can't seem to get it on paper.

What i really can't seem to comprehend, is how to turn the company idea and name into an actual logo. I'm trying to visualize it in various situations where the logo might come up (say sponsorship, commercials, or just on the website), but it is not getting me very far.

So what are the best way to go about this. I have a very clear vision of the produkt, company, and even color scheme. But I can't seem to turn that into a logo which represents all the above like i want to.

It's like looking for something very specific you don't know what looks like.

Comment: It is fairly common to hear people say that they "just can't seem to get it on paper" and at the same time say "I have a very clear idea". Now this is the internal mechanism of your brain taking in. It lies to you about your internal state. If you truly had a clear idea you would have no hard time getting it on paper. But the trick is knowing that your dreams are lies until you manifest them. So the entire process is knowing how your brain lies to you.

Comment: Just for clarification , i meant i have a very clear idea about the business, not the logo. I get what you are saying though, and I know the logo is not in my head somewhere. 

I know exactly what the logo should represent, but how do I channel that into ideas/brainstorms ?

Comment: Yes, but the clear goals applies as much to artificial goals for the logo. Its easy to think that design is solving all the problems. But it often is not its about getting it solved well enough. Sometimes its not possible to include everything you want because it just does not work. So original goals are more like guidelines you never attain that, what you attain is something else that is in the ballpark or the evolved idea of the entire process. Which in very rare cases is whats originally envisioned. So the entire idea that there is a path form here to there is not right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

think about symbolism, you want to incorporate a text and logo together to create an image. Try lots of different ideas. If I was going to create a logo I would start my getting my text and possibly my logo or *rough* logo. After that I would try and put the two together to create something that ticks all of the boxes, once you are done start to create the final logo. If you still cant find the right logo design get some inspiration of other logos or just keep trying the same process. I would recommend doing both.

Comment: what does your design look like?

Comment: broad question, broad answer :)

Comment: I'm looking for the 'thought-process' answer. Because this is really hard to be concrete about. This is a pretty good answer.